# condicion con script marcar y desmarcar

Tags: javascript, html, script

Hola tengo el siguiente script que me selecciona o deselecciona todos mis checkbox, si me funciona y guarda pero quiero saber si se puede que en vez de desmarcar o seleccionar todos marque ciertos checkbox ¿..?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 function marcar(source) 
 {
  checkboxes=document.getElementsByTagName('input'); //obtenemos todos los controles del tipo Input
  for(i=0;i<checkboxes.length;i++) //recoremos todos los controles
  {
   if(checkboxes[i].type == "checkbox") //solo si es un checkbox entramos
   {
    checkboxes[i].checked=source.checked; //si es un checkbox le damos el valor del checkbox que lo llamó (Marcar/Desmarcar Todos)
   }
  }
 }
</script>
```

```html
<div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <h3 style="margin-left:20px;">Coberturas</h3>
                                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Marcar/Desmarcar Todos</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-1"><input type="checkbox" onclick="marcar(this);" class="form-control m-b"></div>

                                    
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Continuacion de Viaje</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-1"><input type="checkbox" name="Coberturas1" value="ROT (Volcadura) 10% Riesgos ordinarios de transito 5% Robo total 20% Huelgas y alborotos populares 5%" class="form-control m-b"></div>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">No Continuacion de Viaje</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-1"><input type="checkbox" name="Coberturas2" value="Riesgos ordinarios de transito (Cobertura Básica) 5% Robo total con violencia y/o asalto 20% Robo parcial con violencia y/o asalto 20% Rapiña, arteria, pillaje y hurto a consecuencia de un riesgo ordinario de transito20% Mojadura y Oxidación 5%" class="form-control m-b"></div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-1"><input type="checkbox" name="Coberturas3" value="Contaminación y Manchas por contacto con otras cargas 5% Rotura y Rajadura 5% Merma 5% Derrame 5% Bodega a bodega 5% Maniobras a bodega 5% Fallas en el sistema de refrigeración y calefacción 5%" class="form-control m-b"></div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-1"><input type="checkbox" name="Coberturas4" value="Maniobras de carga y descarga 5% Estadia en recintos fiscales y fiscalizados por 30 dias 5% Barredura 5% Echazón 5% Barateria del capitán y la tripulación 5% Huelgas y alborotos populares 5% ROT (Volcadura) 10%" class="form-control m-b"></div>
                                </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Caules quieres marcar?

Comment: Quiero marcar los 3 checkbox de abajo como en la primera imagen

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo agregando una clase asi:

```js
 function marcar(source) 
 {
  checkboxes=document.getElementsByClassName('noCont'); //obtenemos todos los controles del tipo Input
  for(i=0;i<checkboxes.length;i++) //recoremos todos los controles
  {
   if(checkboxes[i].type == "checkbox") //solo si es un checkbox entramos
   {
    checkboxes[i].checked=source.checked; //si es un checkbox le damos el valor del checkbox que lo llamó (Marcar/Desmarcar Todos)
   }
  }
 }
```

```html
<div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <h3 style="margin-left:20px;">Coberturas</h3>
                                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Marcar/Desmarcar Todos</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-1"><input type="checkbox" onclick="marcar(this);" class="form-control m-b"></div>

                                    
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Continuacion de Viaje</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-1"><input type="checkbox" name="Coberturas1" value="ROT (Volcadura) 10% Riesgos ordinarios de transito 5% Robo total 20% Huelgas y alborotos populares 5%" class="form-control m-b"></div>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">No Continuacion de Viaje</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-1"><input type="checkbox" name="Coberturas2" class="noCont" value="Riesgos ordinarios de transito (Cobertura Básica) 5% Robo total con violencia y/o asalto 20% Robo parcial con violencia y/o asalto 20% Rapiña, arteria, pillaje y hurto a consecuencia de un riesgo ordinario de transito20% Mojadura y Oxidación 5%" class="form-control m-b"></div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-1"><input type="checkbox" name="Coberturas3" class="noCont" value="Contaminación y Manchas por contacto con otras cargas 5% Rotura y Rajadura 5% Merma 5% Derrame 5% Bodega a bodega 5% Maniobras a bodega 5% Fallas en el sistema de refrigeración y calefacción 5%" class="form-control m-b"></div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-1"><input type="checkbox" name="Coberturas4" class="noCont" value="Maniobras de carga y descarga 5% Estadia en recintos fiscales y fiscalizados por 30 dias 5% Barredura 5% Echazón 5% Barateria del capitán y la tripulación 5% Huelgas y alborotos populares 5% ROT (Volcadura) 10%" class="form-control m-b"></div>
                                </div>
```

Comment: Genial si me funciono, oye se podra que con el primer checkbox seleccionado al momento de darle clic al de marcar/desmarcar todos se desmarque y marque los 3 restantes?